# Filtering array of child components

Tags: reactjs

In the parent component, I have a state array of child components:

```
const [myList, setMyList] = useState([]);

setMyList([
    <MyComponent color='blue' />
    <MyComponent color='blue1' />
    <MyComponent color='blue2' />
    <MyComponent color='red' />
])
```

I display these later on with

```
myList.map(item => item)
```

I sometimes might have a large number of items in the list and would like to have a search box that does `myList.filter()` on the name in the input box.

I have something like this

```
const itemsToHide = myList.filter(item => !item.props.color.includes(e.target.value));
```

This correctly gives me the items that *do not* match the search.

Is there a way to now set display to none to these items?  Or hide them in another way that will not dismount them since when i clear the search box i want them to still be there.

Comment: I would advise against putting components in state. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1248

Comment: @gmoniava Ahhh.... I was actually looking around for quite some time for some articles on common build patterns hoping to find exactly what you just linked.  I couldn't find anything so i opened a new branch to convert from what the article describes to do (which is what i had already written coincidentally) to what I'm asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason to have them in another array? Just checking the condition inside the renderer might be easier. Either wrap your Component in another div

```js
myList.map((item) => {
    const isVisible = item.props.name.includes(searchTerm);
    return (
        <div key={item.props.id} style={{display: `${isVisible ? 'block' : 'none'}`>
          {item}
        </div> 
    )
}
```

or pass a prop and render your component in the same manner. Don't forget to add a unique key to all the divs though.

Answer (score 2):

Just render the items that satisfy the condition:

```
myList
 .filter(item => item.name.includes(searchText))
 .map((item) => 
       (<div key={item.props.id}>
          {item}
       </div> 
  ))
```

Comment: This wouldn’t work because I need all items to mount and when filtered they need to still stay mounted.

Comment: Every time searchText changes, the component will render, and the filter will apply according to searchText value. Did you try?

Comment: Yes, I love this approach and I did it this way for one of my filters but not the other because I only load the items once in the parent component’s useEffect with [] dependency array.  Hmmm I suppose I could put the searchText in the loading useEffect’s dependency array so that it loads the items again after text change